# Map drive with credentials while impersonating a specific user

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, dllimport, impersonation

Before asking the question, let me explain in a few rows the idea. I have the **process A** always running, which launches the **process B** with a specific impersonation (the logged-on user, a specific user, or under system).

The process B will launch cmd and run the `net use` command to map a drive with a specific set of user credentials.

Here's an example:

```
net use <driveLetter>: <networkPath> /persistent:true /user:<username> <password>
```

I'm trying to understand why this is behaving as follows:

**Case 1**: Process B is launched under the logged-on user => drive appears and works

**Case 2**: Process B is launched under a specific user (the same from above, the logged-on on one) => drive does not appear; it appears after you log out and log in again, but can't be accessed as it requires the username and the password

**Case 3**: Process B is launched under a specific user (not the logged on one) => when that user logs in, the drive appears but can't be accessed as it requires the username and the password

**Case 4**: Case 1, but after log out and log in, it has the same behavior like in Case 2 or 3

#### My question

Why is this happening and how can be corrected? Thanks!

#### Impersonation code

This is how I've implemented the impersonation part

```
            //get token for Logged on user mode
            if (impersonationMode == ImpersonationMode.LoggedOnUser)
            {
                var sessionIDs = GetActiveUserInteractiveSessionIDs();

                if (sessionIDs.Count == 0)
                {         
                    throw new Exception("No active session found. Please use a different ImpersonationMode.");
                }
                if (sessionIDs.Count > 1)
                {         
                    throw new Exception("Multiple active sessions found. Please use a different ImpersonationMode.");
                }

                if (WTSQueryUserToken(sessionIDs.FirstOrDefault(), out token))
                {
                    if (!DuplicateTokenEx(
                            token,
                            TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS,
                            ref sa,
                            (int)SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL.SecurityImpersonation,
                            (int)TOKEN_TYPE.TokenPrimary,
                            ref primaryToken))
                    {
                        throw new Exception("Failed to impersonate user");
                    }

                    CloseHandle(token);
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception("Failed to impersonate user");
                }
            }
            else if (impersonationMode == ImpersonationMode.SpecificUser) // Call LogonUser to get a token for the user
            {
                // if domain name was blank, assume local machine
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(domain))
                    domain = Environment.MachineName;

                bool loggedOn = LogonUser(username,
                    domain,
                    password,
                    LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE,
                    LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT,
                    ref token);

                if (!loggedOn)
                {
                    throw new SessionStateUnauthorizedAccessException("Invalid username or password");
                }

                //Convert the impersonation token into Primary token 
                var retVal = DuplicateTokenEx(
                    token,
                    TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS,
                    ref sa,
                    (int)SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL.SecurityImpersonation,
                    (int)TOKEN_TYPE.TokenPrimary,
                    ref primaryToken);

                //Close the Token that was previously opened. 
                CloseHandle(token);
                if (retVal == false)
                {
                    string message = String.Format("DuplicateTokenEx Error: {0}", Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
                    Debug.WriteLine(message);
                }

                // Load user profile
                ProfileInfo profileInfo = new ProfileInfo();
                profileInfo.dwSize = Marshal.SizeOf(profileInfo);
                profileInfo.lpUserName = username;
                profileInfo.dwFlags = 1;
                bool loadSuccess = LoadUserProfile(primaryToken, ref profileInfo);
                if (!loadSuccess)
                {
                    throw new SessionStateUnauthorizedAccessException("Invalid username or password");
                }
            }
```

Comment: not really a direct answer but I'd consider using the WNetAddConnection2 API and try the dwFlags to try and achieve the desired behavior - and you can check the result of the API. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnetwk/nf-winnetwk-wnetaddconnection2a & https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wnet/adding-a-network-connection

Comment: thanks, @kvr! I'll try to switch to this one if I get no answers that can help fix the issue a bit faster as I'm pretty close to a release date :)...the neverending problem

Comment: for what you call `DuplicateTokenEx` ? `LogonUser` and `WTSQueryUserToken` already return primary token

Comment: I might be wrong but I think the LogonUser returns the impersonation token. The WTSQueryUserToken is used for the logged on branch where I have the sessionId

Comment: LogonUser returns the impersonation token only in case `LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK`. for `LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE` you got primary token. `WTSQueryUserToken` always return primary token.

Comment: *run the net use* not exist any sense. need call `WNetAddConnection2`. connection is logon id (luid) bassed

Comment: We don't know how you verified your observations.